# How to create EBS volume using AWS SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, aws-ssm

I am new to AWS SSM. Could anyone help me to how create a EBS volume using AWS System service management (SSM).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 Systems Manager (SSM) is a nice product that is designed to help manage Windows and Linux operating systems.

You cannot create EBS volumes with SSM. You can use SSM to run tools that manage what is on an EBS volume.

Here is a good video on YouTube that will help you understand the capabilities of SSM.

[Deep Dive with Amazon EC2 Systems Manager](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmpxZsk9N48)